# Does the frequency of cases matter for performance of CASE in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case, conditional-statements

Should I start the CASE order of conditions with the most frequent case? Suppose in my db I have 3 products. Product no. 1. stands for 70% of all cases, Product no. 2 stands for 29% of cases and Product no. 1% of cases.

Is it the best order of condition with respect to performance?

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Product=1 THEN 'Most popular case'
        WHEN Product=2 THEN 'Not very popular'
        WHEN Product=3 THEN 'Very rare case'
    END AS Frequency
```

Just to be well understood. Is this the worse order?

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Product=3 THEN 'Very rare case'
        WHEN Product=2 THEN 'Not very popular'
        WHEN Product=1 THEN 'Most popular case'
    END AS Frequency
```

I know that the order of CASE statement matters for query execution and it quits as soon as finds first TRUE condition. But my question is about the frequency of CASEs.

Comment: I guess you are underestimating the query optimizer. In my opinion it's better to concentrate on writing correct and readable sql queries than to micro-optimize things which have a  questionable benefit.

Comment: It is very easy to check which cases are most popular and put them on top of the query. I just want to confirm if it matters.

Comment: Optimizing the `SELECT` is in general not so important since you should care more about the `WHERE` which has to find the records first. So if you have billion records and your select returns 10 of them you are optimizing those 10 records.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I am wondering what other information you are looking for other than the one already described in my posted answer?

Comment: I want to just add a summary column to final huge table based on conditions. Conditions are complex based on many columns. So if the frequency of cases matters I would like to grab advantage of it. I am not doing any further queries on it. Then in the end I want to make a select based on the results of CASE.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin Then doesn't my answer also answer your question then?
From documentation: "The CASE statement evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops with the first condition whose condition is satisfied." so YES, having a CASE with a higher % chance of occurring first will also increase the chance that you have a shorter run time. It does NOT however guarantee it, the obscure case might still haven and be evaluated last resulting in a longer execution time. Depending on your data this can vary, to be sure execute both versions and average the time to see which one suits you better.

Answer (score -1):

The actual effect of the order of the CASE statements matters very little in this example. The query optimizer will decide for itself what the most optimal execution plan is and act accordingly.

If you are really wondering about the CASE statement itself then like you said if CASE quits after it finds its first true then having a more commonly occurring event evaluated first will more likely yield shorter execution times theoretically.

so YES, having a CASE with a higher % chance of occurring first will also increase the chance that you have a shorter run time. It does NOT however guarantee it, the obscure case might still haven and be evaluated last resulting in a longer execution time. Depending on your data this can vary, to be sure execute both versions and average the time to see which one suits you better.

EDIT:(in the event you wanted to control execution flow): as you can read in the CASE documentation: The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures.